# How to format on "auto save" using VS Code? Currently, it only formats on manual save (ex. control+s)

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosave

I have VS Code configured for formatting on saving and also configured for auto-saving after delay using the following settings:

```
{
   ...
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
   "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
   ...
}
```

But, it does not format when auto-saving, only if I explicitly save, such as using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

How can I get it to format automatically?

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe this is currently possible, see [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45997) for further discussion.

[As pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651476/how-to-format-on-auto-save-using-vscode-currently-it-formats-when-i-use-cont/78214155#comment128149397_59651514), this is now possible with the use of extensions. There are two extensions suggested in the thread I originally linked:

1. [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save)
2. [Format on auto save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BdSoftware.format-on-auto-save)

Both require adding a bit of configuration to your `settings.json`, check out the thread for info on how to do that.

Comment: read till the new messages of the thread - it is possible with some additional flags

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel Thanks for pointing that out, added an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following configuration:

```
{
   ...
   "editor.formatOnSave": true,
   "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"
   ...
}
```

Do not use `"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"` as that doesn't work with auto formatting.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45997.

Answer (score 0):

In your vs code press keys `ctrl`+`shift`+`p` then search `settings.json` and write the following code

```
{
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveWhenNoErrors": true,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
    "notebook.formatOnSave.enabled": true
}
```

Comment: The question was about formatting on **auto-save**. The question author already mentioned `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, and they said "*But, it does not format when auto-saving, only if I explicitly save using control+S*"

Comment: thanks for bringing that to my attention! I added some more options and It's working on my device, Hope it will work for you also @GinoMempin